# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception when accessing non null variable

Tags: swift, macos, apple-pdfkit

As you can see in the linked image, I am getting:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

when accessing `outline.numberOfChildren`
but `lldb` shows that outline is not `nil` and that `outline.numberOfChildren` is 0 (which is exactly what it should be in this case). Why is this happening?
Thanks.

link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/quzUC.jpg

Code:

```
 func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool { 
  if self.rootOutline != nil {
     if let outline = item as? PDFOutline {
         if outline.numberOfChildren == 0 {  // <- Error here
            return false
          }
         return true
       }
     if self.rootOutline!.numberOfChildren == 0 {
       return false
       }
     return true
    }
  return false
 }
```

link to Xcode project on github: https://github.com/raphaelreyna/Chapters

Comment: You should post the code in the question rather than use a screenshot, that is probably why the question got downvoted.

Comment: Peter Ruppert, thanks for the edit.

Comment: No problem, good luck!

Comment: Is `NSOutline` a typo? I found no documents about it and your git hub says `PDFOutline` at the same place.

Comment: Ricky Mo, yeah it's a typo, it should say PDFOutline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outline is lazily loaded and can't load if the `PDFDocument` is released from memory. Solution: keep a strong reference to the `PDFDocument`.

Comment: But isn't `if let outline = item as? PDFOutline` creating the strong reference you mention?

Comment: This worked, thanks Willeke. I never would have guessed that this was the issue.

Comment: @Cristik `item` is a strong reference to a `PDFOutline` but the `PDFOutline` items don't keep a strong reference to the document, `document` is a weak property of `PDFOutline`. `outlineRoot` is a strong property of `PDFDocument`. Creating a strong reference in `outlineView(_:isItemExpandable:)` wouldn't work because the document is already released.